# Обновление html на нескольких сайтах

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb

Возникла вот какая задача: существут n сайтов с одинаковыми блоками с идентичными атрибутами. Количество сайтов может расти, а атрибуты периодически нуждаются в актуализации, что в перспективе делает их изменение вручную довольно запарным.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, способ оптимизации этого действия, чтобы разом заменить атрибут на всех сайтах. К каким технологиям присмотреться?

Comment: Очень зависит от инструментов с помощью которых сделаны эти сайты

Comment: Сайты все простейшие лендинги. HTML/CSS + минимум JS скриптов и кое-где PHP формы и комментарии.

Comment: Как вариант на едином сервере можете задать эти атрибуты в виде хеш-таблицы, даже не обязательно в бд хранить, отдавать запросом в виде json, каждый Ваш сайт на клиенте делает запрос на этот сервер для получения атрибутов, дальше должен быть скрипт который применяет полученные атрибуты к Вашему блоку.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, что если я буду хранить значение атрибута в json на облаке, например, firestore?

Comment: хорошее решение.